# how to check wether a form input has file laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to check whether form has file or not of it has I want to upload it to server and save path if not then ignore and run old dB saved path query

Comment: show me some code what you tried ?

Comment: [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#files)

Answer (score 3):

You can try in this way first validate your all inputs as per your requirement then check  for the file in this way :
Am assuming logo file here from form filed :

```
if($request->hasFile('logo')){

            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('logo')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('logo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore=$filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('logo')->move('webimg/', $fileNameToStore);
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore=  $path;
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `hasFile` method on the request:

```
if ($request->hasFile('name_of_file_input_fiels')) {
    //
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($request->file('name_of_file_input_fields')) {

}
```

you can check also this way.

Answer (score 0):

use laravel File validator

```
$rules = array(
    'file' => 'required'
);
```

You can check documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-file)

Here is an example: [Tutorial with file upload validation](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-fileimage-upload-example-with-validationexample.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.

```
$request->hasfile('your key');
```